# Add char to beginning and end of a string

Tags: c, string

I have a function which receives a string as an input. I need to add a char in the beginning and end, something like `'<' ++ "example" ++ '>'` to get an output like `<example>`.

Is there a function already for this or i need to write it myself?

Comment: there is no already existing function

Comment: Use strcat() function! But first strcopy() them in two variables

Comment: "Is there a function already for this" C is the wrong language for such questions.

Comment: to clarify - there is no function that does exactly what you want, you need strcpy, strcat and maybe direct access to string chars. Or sprintf - that would do it too

Comment: You need to write it yourself. You'll need a buffer for the output that's big enough to hold the output string plus a NUL terminator. Then you can `sprintf(output, "<%s>", input)` to create the output string from the input string.

Comment: @DeiDei - how can c be the wrong language?

Comment: Do you actually need to transform `"example"` into `"<example>"` in your code, or just _print_ `"<example>"`?

Comment: Thanks! The function is easy to write, the thing is it will be executed over 1mil times every time i run the main function, so the performance really matters and i assume the pre-written functions are the most efficient ones.

Comment: @pm100 The standard library couldn't exactly be called vast and you're more or less expected to know how to write things like this. The OP is looking for a precise function that does exactly this, or I misunderstood the question.

Comment: "Is there a function already for this" --> `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "<%s>", "example");`

Comment: I need to change/create the string with the "<>", if it was printing i only need to add it to the print ("<%s>") xD

Comment: @chux - still gotta think about ownership of buf

Comment: @DeiDei - C lib is full of weird complex functions - strtok for example. strtok is perfectly doable in 'plain C'. Its just that you know that this isnt one of the weird things

Comment: @pm100 Re: [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052254/c-add-char-to-beginning-and-end-of-a-string?noredirect=1#comment87121161_50052254): Perhaps `char buf[snprintf(0, 0, "<%s>", "example") + 1];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "<%s>", "example");`?  But OP's post is too unspecific about application requirements,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of functions that can do that:

- [`sprintf`, `snprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)
- [`strcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat)

to name a few. Which one you should use depends on your needs. The most
versatile of all are in opinion `sprintf` and `snprintf`. For example:

```
char result[100];
const char *middle = "example";

// the snprintf solution
snprintf(result, sizeof result, "<%s>", middle);

// the strcat solution
result[0] = '\0';
strcat(result, "<");
strcat(result, middle);
strcat(result, ">");
```

You can pick any version you like, but I think the `snprintf` is better overall
than `strcat` solution.

Comment: the problem is that he wanted chars to be appended.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 appended to the source?

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thank you! Never heard of snprintf, seems really useful !!

Comment: @PedroLima take a look at the page I linked in the answer. This presents to you the whole `printf` family of functions. The are very good for different situations. I have used in production code every single one of these functions at some point or another.

Comment: reminder - this will not work as a function since you cannot return result

Comment: @pm100 yep, that's right. But you can declare `char result[100];` in `main` and the pass that array to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the example:

```
char *append(char before, char *str, char after)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if(before)
    {
        memmove(str + 1, str, ++len);
        *str = before;
    }
    if(after)
    {
        str[len] = after;
        str[len + 1] = 0;
    }
    return str;
}
```